# How can we access pseudo html elements using selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can we access pseudo html elements using selenium webdriver? Example `input::after`, `input::before` etc. These elements contents are not displayed in dom but is visible on page.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say we have following `HTML` structure (borrowed from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_before)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
  <head>
    <style>
      p::before {
        content: "Read this -";}
    </style>
  </head>    
  <body contenteditable="false">   
    <p>My name is Donald</p>
    <p>I live in Ducksburg</p>
    <p><b>Note:</b> For this selector to work in IE8, a DOCTYPE must be declared, and you must use the old, single-colon CSS2 syntax (:before instead of ::before).</p>
  </body>    
</html>
```

To get `content` of `:before` pseudo-element you might use following `JavaScript` inserted in `Selenium` code:

**Python**

```
driver.execute_script("return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('p'), ':before').getPropertyValue('content');")
```

**Java**

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('p'), ':before').getPropertyValue('content');");
```

Returned value: `"Read this -"`